# How to test the script deployed with crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a script which I need to run daily at `01.00 am` of every month. This is what I did with cron tab to make it happen

```
#housekeeping
0 1 1 * * sh /product/abc/tools/housekeeper.sh -t ABC
```

How can I check whether this `script` is running? Do I have to wait till it runs or is there a process running for this script so that I can confirm it is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to test crontab scripts follows these guidelines:

1. Set the time pattern to "ten minutes from now". Wait ten minutes. Check `cron`'s logfile and the log files of your script/app for errors.
2. Set the desired time pattern

This way, you can make sure that the script works. If something breaks, it must be because of the time pattern.

You should also redirect all output of the script to a log file. `cron` will send a mail with any output that the script produces but that's rarely desired.

If you always add an entry like "${timestamp} Started" to the log, you can check at your leisure that the script worked as expected.

If you want both, then you must make your script/app write the log file itself (i.e. without output redirection in the `crontab`) and print any errors to `stdout`; this will then make `cron` send an email.

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing I use is to append something to a particular file before and after the desired command, like

`*/2 * * * * (echo "Starting" >> ~/monitorCron.log; <Actual operation>; echo "End" >> ~/monitorCron.log;) > ~/cron.log 2>&1`

This runs every 2 minutes, and appends the strings to `~/monitorCron.log`.

This is the same thing I do in programming, writing a print statement where-ever and when-ever I  get a doubt.